# Importing CMS pages from Homestead to Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, import, cms-pages

We are using **Magento 2.0**. Our previous website was on **Homestead CMS**. `We want to bring all the pages` from **homestead** to **Magento 2.0**. Please help

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to copy the content manually from Homestead into the (WYSIWYG) editor for CMS pages in M2, as there is no pre-built solution. It would be a hassle to import them from a completely different environment into the M2 database. It's probably not worth your time to program something for this, or do you have that many CMS pages?

Comment: We have around 39 pages to import

Comment: We have support of CMS pages import from any csv format in our commercial (400$) extension - Improved Import https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-import-magento-2-cms-pages.html